# Неправильно работает $result->fetch_assoc(); при использовании через переменную

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть код:

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['psw'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE Name='$login' AND Password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$res = $result->fetch_assoc();

if (empty($res) == 1) {
    echo "Неверный логин или пароль!";
}
else {
    while($row = $res){
        echo  $row['Name'];
        echo  ' - ';
        echo  $row['Surname'];
        echo  '<br>';
    }
}
```

Если я использую *$result->fetch_assoc()* через переменную $res, то при вводе верного пароля бесконечно выводится один и тот же результат из базы данных. При прямом использовании всё было нормально, пока не добавил скрипт проверки "Неверный логин или пароль".

Comment: В таком варианте `$res` не меняется, поэтому и получается бесконечный цикл в `while($row = $res)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы один раз получили $res и больше он у вас никогда не меняется. Его нужно каждый раз вызывать в цикле. Вопрос следующий. Я так понимаю, вы собираетесь выводить только одного юзера. Зачем вам вообще здесь какой-то цикл?

```php
$login = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['login']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['psw']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE Name='$login' AND Password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$res = $result->fetch_assoc();
if (!$res) {
    echo "Неверный логин или пароль!";
}
else {
    echo  $res['Name'];
        echo  ' - ';
        echo  $res['Surname'];
        echo  '<br>';
}
```

И всегда экранируйте принимаемые значения в SQL-запросах, если не хотите например базу потом из бэкапа восстанавливать

Comment: У вас будет ошибка в 6 строке. `$res` не найдена...

Comment: @Knyaz71 спасибо что заметили. Поправил

Comment: У меня суть проекта  - это уязвимая для SQL-иньекции страница, поэтому использую цикл (чтобы выводились все подходящие значения). При втором обращении к $result->fetch_assoc() ничего не выводится, поэтому использую через переменную

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла функция mysqli_num_rows(), таким образом у меня есть код:

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['psw'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE Name='$login' AND Password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 0) {
    echo "Неверный логин или пароль!";
}
else {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo  $row['Name'];
        echo  ' - ';
        echo  $row['Surname'];
        echo  '<br>';
    }
}
```

который исправно работает. Обратите внимание, что скрипт уязвим.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).